# Direct Database Access

Tags: sql, database

This question may sound dumb but even after going through so many post I am not clear thats why seeking help

What is Direct database access? Using Connection strings in the program with the JDBC/ODBC drivers is an example of Direct Access?

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 types of JDBC - Driver Types

1. Type 1: JDBC-ODBC Bridge Driver
2. Type 2: JDBC-Native API
3. Type 3: JDBC-Net pure Java
4. Type 4: 100% Pure Java

**Type 4 drive** provides the direct access. In a Type 4 driver, a pure Java-based driver communicates directly with the vendor's database through socket connection. This is the highest performance driver available for the database and is usually provided by the vendor itself.

**Example** : MySQL's Connector/J driver is a Type 4 driver.

**Referece**
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-driver-types.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think no matter use JDBC/ODBC, or cmd even you can implement in your own code to access database, it just use series standard API to make connections and deal affairs, and there is no essential difference.

It is just my personal opinion.